# Protractor test timeout after ui-router $state change - after a move from JSPM to webpack

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, protractor, webpack, jspm

Recently my Angular.js project has been moved from using JSPM over to webpack. Everything works fine, except the protractor end-to-end tests.

After much searching, it *seems* to be caused by a state change in angular-ui-router.
`this.$state.go(value);`

Effectively everything works up until this point. After a `$state` change has occurred I am getting timeouts on any protractor element selection.

Known workarounds:

- Seeking help I have tried setting `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` after the `$state` change which then allows element selection to work again.
- Another workaround found is to force a reload of the page after a `$state` change, and then select the element to test.

Ideally, the cause of not being able to find elements would be nice to know, especially when using JSPM we don't encounter this problem. My suspicions are that the `waitForAngular()` method isn't able to find the angular app after the `$state` change.

This all occurs on a single page angular application.

Any help appreciated, thanks!